# Having CloudFormation wait for the user data

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have a cloudformation stack which creates a EC2 instance and install something in it using UserData.  Cloudformation immediately reports **CREATE_COMPLETE** upon creation of the EC2 instance based on RedHat.  But at this point, the instance is not really usable since the userdata takes about 40 min to finish. I read through documentation and even tried cfn-signal but I could not successfully execute it.

Can someone tell me how exactly it has to be done?

```
EC2Instance:
  Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
  Properties:
    CreditSpecification:
      CPUCredits: standard
    IamInstanceProfile:
      Fn::ImportValue:
        !Sub ${InstanceProfileStackName}-instanceProfile
    ImageId: !Ref ImageId
    InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior: stop
    InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
    SubnetId: !Ref SubnetId
    SecurityGroupIds:
      - !Ref DefaultSecurityGroup
      - !Ref WebSecurityGroup
    UserData:
      Fn::Base64: !Sub |
        #!/bin/bash
        set -e
        yum update -y
```

The above is the truncated part of my Cloudformation template.

**UPDATE**

I have the script which has the following line

```
source scl_source enable rh-python36
```

The default of my instance is python2.7 but I had to install my pip packages with python3.6. I am not sure if that was making the cfn-signal fail.

The script is going till the final step and seems to fail there. I am creating a recordset from the EC2 IP but Cloudformation still thinks the EC2 instance is not done and waiting till the timeout.

Screenshot of the instance snapshot
[image: This is the screenshot from the image snapshot from EC2 console]

Log file end is as follows
[image: This the end of my log file]

Also my log file is named /var/log/cloud-init.log. There was no cloud-init-output.log in that directory.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/60381063/3390419

Comment: Specifically you're missing `CreationPolicy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could recreate your error and fixed here. Here is the corrected template. I added to the answer from Marcin

```
EC2Instance:
  Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
  CreationPolicy: 
    ResourceSignal:
      Timeout: PT5M # Specify the time here
  Properties:
    CreditSpecification:
      CPUCredits: standard
    IamInstanceProfile:
    Fn::ImportValue:
      !Sub ${InstanceProfileStackName}-instanceProfile
    ImageId: !Ref ImageId
    InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior: stop
    InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
    SubnetId: !Ref SubnetId
    SecurityGroupIds:
      - !Ref DefaultSecurityGroup
      - !Ref WebSecurityGroup
    UserData:
      Fn::Base64: !Sub |
        #!/bin/bash -ex
        yum update -y
        source scl_source enable rh-python36
        <Your additional commands>
        cfn-signal -e $? --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource EC2Instance --region ${AWS::Region}
```

You might want to counter check the indentation before trying.

Answer (score 2):

You need **two components**:

- [CreationPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-creationpolicy.html) so that CFN waits for a SUCCESS signal from the instance.
- [cfn-signal](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-signal.html) helper script to perform the signalling action.

Thus your template could be modified as follows for Redhat 8:

```
EC2Instance:
  Type: AWS::EC2::Instance

  CreationPolicy: # <--- creation policy with timeout of 5 minutes
    ResourceSignal:
      Timeout: PT5M

  Properties:
    CreditSpecification:
      CPUCredits: standard
    IamInstanceProfile:
      Fn::ImportValue:
        !Sub ${InstanceProfileStackName}-instanceProfile
    ImageId: !Ref ImageId
    InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior: stop
    InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
    SubnetId: !Ref SubnetId
    SecurityGroupIds:
      - !Ref DefaultSecurityGroup
      - !Ref WebSecurityGroup
    UserData:
      Fn::Base64: !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash -x

          yum update -y

          yum -y install python2-pip

          pip2 install https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest.tar.gz

          python2 /usr/bin/cfn-signal -e $? \
                 --stack ${AWS::StackName} \
                 --resource EC2Instance \
                 --region ${AWS::Region}
```

For **debugging**, as the user data may error out, have to login to the instance and check `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` file

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped me a step ahead. Unfortunately, the last part of the script seems to fail. More in the update