# How to set the administrator password for a Windows Server machine on AWS from CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, windows-server

I am deploying a CloudFormation template which launches an EC2 instance from the *Windows_Server-2019-English-Full-Base-2020.05.13* AMI.

By default, the Windows Server image has an `Administrator` user. To connect to the instance via RDP, I have to navigate to the console, click on *Connect* and then get the generated random password from the console.

Is there a way I can set the RDP password to a custom value? I would like to do this from the CloudFormation template, in the UserData section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The solution was to use the following **command in `UserData`**:

```
net user Administrator "new_password"
```

The command, as explained in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-passwords.html), can be used to change admin password.

This works because  `UserData` executes under administrator account ([ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-user-data.html#user-data-execution)):

> User data scripts are executed from the **local administrator account** when a random password is generated.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this does not work.  Can you provide any more information?  Does this work with all Windows server AMIs?

Comment: @blong Please make a new question, dedicated to your issue with relevant details.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness and future reference, here's what the CloudFormation template now looks like:

```
"UserData": {
    "Fn::Base64": {
        "Fn::Join": [
            "",
            [
            "<powershell>\n",
            "net user Administrator ",
            {
                "Ref": "Password"
            },
            "\n",
            "</powershell>\n"
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

where `Password` is a CloudFormation string parameter with the password.