# How do I create EC2 instance using CloudFormation w/ Session Manager installed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-session-manager

I want to create an EC2 instance using CloudFormation.
I also want to run a powershell script from the Ec2 instance using Session Manager (instead of me having to RDP into the machine and running it that way)

What exactly would the CloudFormation template include in order to have Session Manager work right out of the box  (said another way, right after the stack is created)
The idea here is to

1. Create Stack for **Windows** Ec2 instance within existing VPC
2. After stack is created, run session manager in AWS Console, executing powershell script

Any insight is appreciated. Thank you in advance for the help with this.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62386380/3390419 adapt it to run your script

Answer (score 0):

Using the userdata for your instance you can ensure that the SSM agent is installed, following [these instructions](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/install-ssm-agent-ec2-linux/) that Amazon provides.

Then in your CloudFormation stack create a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) in your CloudFormation stack and have it depend on your EC2 instance being created.

The custom resource references a Lambda function that you would need to create, this Lambda function would run the SSM document using the SDK on the newly created instance by passing in the instance id as a parameter.

Rather than using session manager, it would use [AWS run command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html) with the "[AWS-RunPowerShellScript](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/ssm-plugins.html#aws-runPowerShellScript)" document which allows the execution of a command on the server without initialising a full session.

Comment: How about for Windows instance?

Comment: For Windows you can use the powershell commands here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-install-win.html In your user data you should be able to wrap them in a `<powershell>COMMANDS GO HERE</powershell>` syntax.

Comment: Awesome. Would you be able to provide a working sample of the script that will provision and setup session manager within a user data? That sounds like that is exactly what I am after.

Comment: Hmm, I don’t have a working answer to hand. The userdata is added to the EC2 instance as a string for this parameter. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-userdata. The link is in the question for custom resources, and the lambda will call the send-command function, here’s an example in the boto3 SDK. https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Client.send_command. The document name is AWS-RunPowerShellScript